# How do I edit text files in the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, text-editors

On Unix I'd just use [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), but I don't know what the command is on Windows. I am actually trying to edit files over SSH with Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I think the accepted answer should be changed to [squillman's](https://superuser.com/questions/186857/how-do-i-edit-text-files-in-the-windows-command-prompt/186859#186859) (as it is the only one that will work on most contemporary PCs - and possibly inside Docker containers).

Comment: [Edit a text file on the console in 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11045077/995714), [Basic text editor in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19497399/995714)

Comment: if you _do_ have a graphic desktop but simply want to edit a file directly from `cmd` then you can use notepad e.g. with `notepad myfile.txt`

Comment: If you have linux subsystem for windows, you can use 'bash' and then any linux subsystem command (I tried nano and it works). I would post this as answer but I can't for some reason.

Comment: @SajanGohil i get the following error when running 'bash nano' from a windows cmd line: "/usr/bin/nano: /usr/bin/nano: cannot execute binary file"

Comment: If your problem cannot be solved by Ubuntu, then you have the wrong problem.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`edit filename`

I won't vouch for its functionality and outdated GUI but it is installed by default, even on Windows 7.

Edit: Except 64 bit versions of Windows.

Comment: On all versions of Windows? There is no "edit" on Windows 7 apparently.

Comment: Odd... evidently it's installed by default on Windows 7 32-bit, but not on Windows 7 64-bit. That's sad.

Comment: This command only freezes when I try to call it!

Comment: @nhinkle: I seem to recall reading something about 16-bit apps being unavailable under 64-bit windows installs.

Comment: It doesn't work on win8 x64.

Comment: It doesn't work on Win10 x64 as well. It seems then they don't have a DOS editor option for 64 bit windows. Now a days `Notepad` and other GUI editors seems to be the only option then.

Comment: How do I install it on Windows 7 64bit?

Comment: Confirmed NOT working in Win 10... I really cant believe Windows is lacking such basic tools and nobody even seems to care

Comment: This is just wrong answer when talking about "Windows" generally. Today, Windows is also Win7-64bit, Win8-64bit, Win8.1-64bit, Win10. "edit" cannot be the correct answer to the question from today's point of view.

Comment: this should not be the accepted answer. who uses 32bit nowadays?

Comment: May I suggest [the standard text editor](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ed.htm)?

Comment: I tried but it isn't working

Comment: Lacking a basic command line editor is one of many reasons why I hate Windows.

Comment: On October 14, 2025, Windows 10 will end support and Windows 11 is only 64-bit so "edit" will no longer exist.

Answer (score 118):

The simplest solution on *all* versions of Windows is:

```
C:\> notepad somefile.txt
```

And, no extra software required.

Comment: Nice, but not over SSH

Comment: Ah. Right. Windows doesn't have a command-line editor built in. You'll probably need to install the Gnu version of the editor you want to use. Since you've already installed the `ssh` server, that should be no problem for you.

Comment: Like BillP3rd said... just run cmd as administrator, then enter notepad filename, save it and that's it. ;)

Comment: Like OP said... "I am actually trying to edit files over ssh..."

Comment: My biggest problem with notepad is it doesn't handle different style newlines.

Comment: useless answer, both for ssh users and for those who wants to edit files **IN** cmd window, not outside it

Comment: This will not work in a Docker container based on 'windowsservercore'

Comment: This answer is soon to be outdated - notepad will no longer be installed by default on windows 10 after the 20h1 update - it will have to be installed from the store, and probably wont be in %PATH%

Comment: @wisbucky it now does for 2 years [Introducing extended line endings support in Notepad](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/)

Answer (score 75):

From a Windows command prompt enter ***copy con*** followed by the target file name. (`copy con c:\file.txt`).

Then enter the text you want to put in the file.

End and save the file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to change text in an existing file simply display the text by using the command `type` followed by the file name and then just copy and paste the text in to the `copy con` command.

Comment: Hard core.  Try not to make any typos, or you'll have to start over again.  Well, backspace does work if you catch the mistake before you press Enter.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with psexec. Tried to edit my hosts file with `copy con hosts` but ^Z doesn't save and ^C doesn't cancel! Had to close the cmd window to get out. The file was unchanged.

Comment: Note: F6 can be used instead of [Ctrl]-[Z]

Comment: In a Docker container based on 'windowsservercore' (CMD), Ctrl + C worked for the terminating key sequence.

Comment: I remember this hack from MS-DOS but it doesn't seem to work in Windows Powershell.  Probably worth a new Question to clarify.

Answer (score 61):

If you have git installed for windows then most likely nano and vim are both available at

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim.exe
```

To run from a command prompt (cmd.exe)

```
"c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe" <filename>
```

To run in powershell

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe' <filename>
```

They both work great even over ssh.

Comment: Thank you! Git imo is a more reasonable dependency that's likely already on the server, as opposed to WSL or other 3rd-party text editors.

Comment: This is the perfect answer!

Comment: This should be the Accepted Answer. People running ssh will mostly have git installed as well. Otherwise, nano or vim could be installed through gui once, and then be used

Comment: I added the directory `c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` to the path in Windows, now it feels like having a Linux inside Windows. Nice!

Comment: this should be marked as answer. 

Answer (score 31):

If you're used to vi and don't want to settle for the built-in editor you can get [**Vim for Windows**](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc). It'll run from a command shell. Or try [WinVi](http://www.winvi.de).

Comment: this should me marked as answer because `edit` has been removed from win 10

Comment: It is much better than that: It also works inside a Windows Docker container (it is easiest to get the "Win32 console executable", e.g. [vim81w32.zip](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim81w32.zip) - unzip and copy `vim.exe` to wherever it is accessible in the Docker container).

Comment: vi/vim is my go to, can recommend chocolatey package manager - `choco install vim`

Comment: `winget install vim.vim` also works (assuming you've updated the URL of the source `winget` to the current `https://winget.azureedge.net/cache` - I've encountered installations with an old source URL).

Answer (score 16):

Believe it or not, [`EDLIN.EXE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490632.aspx) is still around *`<shudder>`* at least on this Vista system.

Excuse me while I sob softly to myself...

Comment: It was finally deleted in Windows 7 (at least the 64-bit versions).

Comment: @jason404: It's still included in 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: edlin is a 16-bit program, therefore it is not available in 64-bit versions of Windows. However, I won't be surprised if someone here claims it's still present in the 32-bit version of Windows 10.

Comment: @TSJNachos117 It is indeed in x86 Windows 10.

Comment: Not surprised at all.

Comment: Someone compiled `edlin` for Windows 10: [Native edlin on windows 10 (!)](https://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/2019/05/25/native-edlin-on-windows-10/).

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about SSH, or anything (else?) server-related, so forgive me if this "solution" is useless. If you want to edit files in the command prompt, you can get the Windows version of [Nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php).

As a side note, those little `^` signs at the bottom of the window are supposed to represent the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button. For instance, `^X Exit` means that you can exit the program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>.

Also, Nano will sometimes add extra newlines when saving files. This seems to be some kind of bug with Nano's word wrapping.

I've also seen ports of [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) for Windows, although I've used one that just seem to make command prompt window as small as it can be, leaving only a title bar (which means the rest of the window may as well be invisible, since you can't see what you're doing). However, the [Windows version of Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) seems to work quite nicely.

Comment: Before lookig for those  "may work but are useless solutions" i thought for a Windows port of Nano. It's using cygwin.dll and nothing more. I've picket the lightest version i can, from https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/nano/nano/1.0.8/nano-1.0.8.zip. Thank you.

Comment: As @gman pointed out, if you have git installed, then you already have `nano.exe`.  Also, it's pretty easy to install nano via the command line by using chocolatey ( https://chocolatey.org/install#individual ).  After chocolatey is installed, install nano by typing `choco install nano`.

Answer (score 7):

2020 UPDATE:

On Win10 just enable the linux subsystem then you'll have most of the linux stuff like `vim` and `nano`:

```
c:> bash
$: nano yourfile.txt
```

Comment: The linux subsystem? Is that a thing now in W10?

Comment: OK, just googled this - good idea, but installing an entire linux distro to enable a terminal editor? It's a stretch. Still might try it tho' ;)

Comment: Having to fire up a VM solely for the purpose of editing a file isn't a good idea..., well unless one wants to change their shell completely, which is a good idea!

Comment: Using WSL doesn't necessarily solve the problem conveniently since it can't necessarily access the main Windows partition.

Answer (score 5):

Use *vim* or *nano*.

Install *vim* with with `choco install vim` using the [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package manager.

(There might be [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/) version available as well, but I haven't checked.)

Although *nano* also exists as *choco* package, it is very outdated. Instead manually install [this nano](https://github.com/lhmouse/nano-win). However, when using over SSH, *nano* control characters get a bit confused, so you may lose some, since windows use it's own API for controlling screen characters, and not POSIX. So although a lot of work is currently in progress for future Win10 compatibility.

Then you can run with: `nano -cg some.txt`, but the cursor will only show up at the right location when you push `CTRL-L`. (Which is why *vim* is preferred.)

Comment: Of course, this requires having Chocolately installed

Comment: Thanks mic, I added that link.

Comment: **UPDATE:** *Nano* now works as expected in Windows-10, just make sure you are using UTF-8 in your terminal have a compatible font.

Comment: chocolatey is the way.

Answer (score 4):

**2021 UPDATE**

As @phuclv has mentioned in comments, I want to emphasize that **there is a tool that actually works** great on Windows 64 bit too! It's called ***Micro*** and fortunately, it is quite feature-rich, regularly updated and alive.

To install it, you only need to download the latest version's 64bit.zip file [from here](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/releases), and then unzip it somewhere and add its path to your PATH. No dependencies or external files are needed — just the binary and you're done.

[image]

**Quick Start:**

- Just type `micro` to create and edit a new text file.
- Type `micro <filename>` to start editing an already-made file.
- To save: `ctrl + s`
- To see a list of keybindings: `alt + g`
- To quit: `ctrl + q`

**Some Exciting Features:**

- **Select text easily (using the shift key, or even using your mouse!**), and then copy, cut, paste or delete the selected text using the same keybindings common in your operating system(e.g. `ctrl + c` for copy on Windows).
- **Supporting so many common keybindings**, e.g. `ctrl + d` to duplicate a line, or activate multiple curser mode and etc.
- Undo / Redo
- **Syntax Highlighting** (for more than 130 programming languages)
- Plugin System
- Typed Commands (instead of using keybindings)
- ...

**A tip on using Micro for VSCode users:**

Since both VSCode and Micro try to support all common keybindings, you'll probably have a lot of conflicting keybindings between them when using Micro inside the VSCode's embedded CMD/PowerShell terminal. For instance, to quit Micro, you will have to use `ctrl + q` while it is the VSCode's keybinding for the "Quick Open View" command.

But *no worries*! Micro also supports "Typed Commands" which allow you to control the editor using commands instead of keybindings. So you can type commands and you're fine to use Micro on VSCode as well. However, there's still a tiny problem. To enable "*command mode*" on Micro, you have to use `ctrl + e`, which is also a keybinding of VSCode for the "Go To File..." command. So you have to change the `ctrl + e` keybinding either on VSCode or on Micro to get rid of this conflict and then you're all set.

Personally, I preferred to change Micro's `ctrl + e`. Here are the steps from the [documentation](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/blob/master/runtime/help/keybindings.md) to change it to `ctrl + w` (or whatever else non-conflicting keybinding of your own liking) on a Windows machine:

1. Open `%userprofile%/.config/micro/bindings.json` with any editor.
2. Add this line to the end of the JSON: `"Ctrl-w": "CommandMode"`
3. Save.
   Now to enter command mode, press `ctrl + w` and type your commands (e.g.: quit, save, open, etc).

Comment: This is a nice option BUT it is a 10MB executable.  Not exactly a lightweight option.  If someone wants to bundle micro with their software, it bloats the download by 4MB (compressed).  Would like to see a Notepad-esque CLI (no syntax highlighting, intentionally limited feature set, etc) that is about 200KB in size uncompressed.  The main notepad.exe that comes with Windows is 210KB, so it seems like it should be doable.

Comment: To be honest, I found the screen recording really confusing, not to mention the talk about VSCode keybinding. If it's a command-line editor, why launch it *inside* VSCode? I literally went to the developer site to check if it's a standalone app. I can't imagine the reason for such a strange edit process. Despite the confusion, it does look pretty good - I might use it instead of VSCode, which is getting annoying

Comment: It works well from the command line in a Windows Server Core editoin (likely also the Nano edition, but not tested). For a simple standalone tool to edit some config files it is great. The quite big binary doesn't bother me there.

Comment: 10MB is tiny by modern standards.

Answer (score 2):

If the remote computer has Windows Subsystem for Linux installed, you can type `bash` to have the next commands interpreted by WSL. From here, you can type `nano FILENAME` or `vim FILENAME` or whatever your preferred Linux text editor is. To exit WSL and return to regular Command Prompt, type `exit` or `logout`.

This came in handy when I was accessing a Windows Jupyter Notebook server and wanted to edit `.gitattributes`, a hidden file which isn't shown in the Jupyter GUI. This answer is based on SajanGohil's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

There is a console file manager called [FAR Manager](https://farmanager.com/) (similar to Norton Commander or Volkov Commander for MS DOS or Midnight Commander for Linux).

You can run the internal FAR Manager text editor using the following command line:

```
far -E <filename>
```

[image: Screenshot]

@Joril says it works  via SSH. I did not have chance to test it.

Another similar solution is to install Midnight Commander as part of the [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) distro or the [standalone app](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcwin32/) and run

```
mcedit <filename>
```

Comment: Didn't know about Far and yes it works via SSH, thanks :)

Comment: @Joril Thanks for letting me know. Added your note to the post.

Answer (score 0):

In the **latest Windows 10 & 11**, you can install **Nano/vim/micro** directly from **Windows Terminal**:

```
winget install Gnu.Nano
winget install vim.vim
winget install zyedidia.micro
```

Comment: I had the exact problem this question had: needing to edit a config file logged into windows 10 x64 over ssh, and `winget install vim.vim` worked great for me. All answers involving wsl in any case all failed, due to an issue that results in the 'The file cannot be accessed by the system." error. I could run vim with `"c:\Program Files\Vim\vim90\vim.exe"` after installing it with winget, and no windows terminal was needed: I was at command line via ssh.