# Windows text editor with command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, text-editors, console

Is there a multipurpose text editor for Windows that has an embedded command line? As an example of what I'm looking for, I've included a screenshot of KDE's Kate below.

[image: Kate editor]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit text files in the Windows command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/186857/how-do-i-edit-text-files-in-the-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: oops this should be closed as off-topic. This should be on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Too bad Kate still doesn't have this feature on Windows build.

Answer (score 3):

Try [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the NppExec plug-in installed. You can install the plug-in using the NotePad++ Plug-in manager.

NppExec Description:

> Run different commands with the help of this plugin NppExec is
>   designed as a Notepad++ plugin that gives you the possibility to run
>   commands and applications directly from the editor.
>
> NppExec can be used for running other programs from Notepad++, passing
>   text from Notepad++ to some external tool, compiling source files
>   (using external compiler) etc.
>
> When the NppExec plugin is installed, you can see its icon "Show
>   Console Dialog" on Notepad++'es toolbar, and you can find NppExec's
>   submenu under Plugins menu of Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

## [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

It has a terminal and also a help text box that can be opened anywhere

[image: VS code interface]

[VS Code User Interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface)