# Edit command in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ms-dos

I'm studying IT and in my current class am learning the basic MS-DOS commands (CD, DIR, TREE, etc...). At the school, I'm using Windows 7, and I don't know how, but I'm still able to run the old EDIT command in DOS.

However, in my Windows 8 (64-bit version) laptop I'm not able to run this command. I know that it's kind of silly to ask for that once I can use a common text editor like Notepad or [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), but only as a way to recreate the environment hat I have in class I'm looking for a way to use the EDIT command.

I've heard some people talking about DOSBox or ExDOS as a solution, but I don't know them.

Comment: The question is: why is your class teaching you ancient technology; why they haven't taught you that MS-DOS is no longer in use, and that the current implementation of those commands is the Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: If you want to use the edit *command*, say to be compatible with preexisting batch files or something, you could write your own edit.bat batch file that just runs another editor: `notepad.exe %1`. Another alternative is to use *echo* to create small text files as suggested in answer to a similar question posted [here at Microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/my-editexe-file-is-missing/b094cf6a-7956-4ef7-975f-94ca50900ae3?auth=1).

Comment: Win7 32-bit still has and can run 16-bit Edit.com, but obviously Win7 64-bit can't and so it's not included. Also see [Modern text editor that mimics MS-DOS EDIT?](http://superuser.com/questions/41083/modern-text-editor-that-mimics-ms-dos-edit), [command line text editor like “edit” for windows x64](http://superuser.com/questions/250522/command-line-text-editor-like-edit-for-windows-x64), [Replacement for edit.exe in 64-bit Windows cmd/powershell](http://superuser.com/questions/369281/replacement-for-edit-exe-in-64-bit-windows-cmd-powershell) etc.

Comment: @Karan: All three links are (effectively) broken now.

Answer (score 1):

While it will work differently (definitely the EDIT utility will not be the same), you can [download a ready-made FreeDOS](http://virtualboxes.org/images/freedos/) virtual machine and run in VirtualBox.

Or, if you have the access, install a 32-bit Windows in a virtual machine and run it there.

Answer (score 0):

The MS-DOS editor (edit.exe) is not present in modern 64 bit Windows. The only option is Notepad. So I did this in the following way.

1. Press <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> → type cmd and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> → in the taskbar right click on the
   Command prompt icon → click pin to task bar → close command prompt.
   Now again right click on the Command prompt icon (that, you have recently pinned) → right click on Command Prompt → click *Properties* → in *Shortcut* tab write **"%windir%\system32\"** (without quotes) in the Start in box → click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
2. Open Command Prompt from the task bar (you have recent pinned the command prompt icon in the task bar)

   ********To View Command prompt (CMD) in full screen Start CMD → right click on the Name bar of CMD → click *Layout* → increase Window Buffer Size width and height***********
3. Type "notepad" without quotes.
4. Write your text and save

You have successfully written, saved and editd a text file on x64 bit Windows using the command prompt".

Answer (score 0):

You can use echo command in windows 10 
Example: 
1: If you want to edit C:/test/now.txt file Command below
Command: >> cd c:/test

> > echo This is a line what adding in now file >> now.txt

2: You can make a file using cmd
   Command: >> cd c:/test

> > echo this is a text file >text.txt

3: You can view a file using cmd
   command: >> cd c:/test

> > type now.txt

Comment: Uh, `edit` does come with a little bit more than overwriting, appending and viewing of file content (e.g. _editing_ it) :)

Answer (score 0):

There IS an edit.com in Windows 10.

This is the way to get it:

- Open a DOS window and click at the top to get a menu: 
  As I am French, the menu is in French.
- Click "Properties" (the last line); You get another menu.
- Just tick the box at the bottom (in French: "Utiliser l'ancienne console", in English probably "Use the old console")

That's all.  Click OK. Close the window and re-open a DOS. It looks slightly different. Type "Edit" and there it is.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Windows 10 1607 x64. [This other answer](http://superuser.com/a/186858/380318) seems to say that it's only there on 32-bit installations; is that what you have?

Comment: I have Windows 10 - 64 bits    Roger

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Comment: In a 64-bit version of Windows 10, the option/checkbox is *"Use legacy console (requires relaunch)"* (in tab *Options*). But after opening a new command prompt, `edit` is still not found (*'edit.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*).

Answer (score 0):

The ‘use legacy console’ option has nothing to do with the ability to run 16-bit applications, it only controls the new terminal. In particular, it will not make EDIT work on 64-bit Windows. Roger Bassaber is either running 32-bit Windows 10 (possibly on 64-bit hardware), or using a different 32-bit or 64-bit editor that also happens to be called EDIT, or lying.

To get EDIT to work on 64-bit Windows, the easiest way is this:

First, download EDIT.COM, it's very easy to find and get online.

Second, download DOSBox.

Third, place a batch file next to the DOSBox executable with the following contents:

```
%0\..\dosbox -noconsole -forcescaler hq2x -c "mount a \"%~dp1\"" -c "mount c \"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOS\"" -c "c:edit /64 a:%~nxs1" -c exit
```

This assumes that you placed EDIT.COM in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\DOS`. You can change the settings as you like. The settings shown here will hide the annoying DOSBox console, enlarge the text to avoid eye-strain when using modern displays, load the file as a binary file with 64 characters per line, and quit DOSBox when EDIT is closed. You could for example remove the /64 to load the file as a text file or add /H to get more rows of text on screen.

You can now drop a file on this batch file to open it in EDIT or invoke the batch file from the command line with the file to edit as the argument.