# Nano alternative for windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I am looking for software similar to nano for linux bash but for windows powershell. Is there any built in so I do not have to install something?

**EDIT** Nano is a text editor that runs within the bash. You can open a text like document (.txt, .c etc) in the bash to edit it on the fly or just view it and close it again.

Comment: I don't know if this works but maybe it's possible to get edit.com off an XP machine and use it in powershell on windows 7.  I don't know if Win7 32bit has edit.com but win7 64bit doesn't have edit.com

Comment: Assume someone knows everything about PowerShell and could help you, but doesn't know much about Linux or what Nano may be. Maybe you should describe what you want to do.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf You were right, I edited it

Comment: Also have a look: https://superuser.com/questions/186857/how-do-i-edit-text-files-in-the-windows-command-prompt/1679682#1679682

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is now a way to use `nano` and `vim` with powershell by installing "Bash on Windows". [More information on Scott Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx)

From command line you can run

```
bash -c "vi filename.txt"
bash -c "nano filename.txt"
```

you can also add those functions to your powershell profile

```
function vi ($File){
    bash -c "vi $File"
}

function nano ($File){
    bash -c "nano $File"
}
```

[The blog source where I got the information from](https://medium.com/powershell-explained/text-editor-inside-powershell-22d2f5e748b8)

Comment: Those [smart quotes](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typographic-tips/smart-quotes) in your post will become stupid to the shells and cause problems. I've fixed them for you this time

Comment: Yes. Since powershell has been updated. Thank you for the updated answer, I swapped the accepted one to yours

Answer (score 45):

Nano is available for powershell. If you have the [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) package manager installed in your system you can install nano with:

```
choco install nano
```

You can install Chocolatey through the command line with:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

My personal experience is that it nano performs great in Windows 10 but it's really slow to start up the first time in Windows 7.

Comment: choco has an old version of nano though (2.x atm). Git for Windows comes with a newer version (4.9.x atm).

Comment: or even better, choco package `msys2` includes nano 7.2, which is *very* up to date (it's the latest version as of right now)

Answer (score 38):

Just install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/wsl/install-win10) (WSL). Then, type.

```
wsl nano
```

or

```
wsl nano textfilenametoedit.txt
```

Quotes are not needed.

Comment: This may be obvious to some people, but it tripped me up for a bit: if you're supplying a full path to the file, make sure you pass the path that you would use in WSL, not in Windows. For example, if you want to edit C:\text.txt, instead of using `wsl nano C:\text.txt`, use `wsl nano /mnt/c/text.txt`

Comment: to see the content, `wsl cat filename`. To see top content: `wsl head filename` . To see tail content> `wsl tail filename`

Answer (score 11):

The only built-in editor in Windows is Notepad. It should already be in your path, so you can just type `notepad something.txt` in the PowerShell console.

If you want console-based editors, there are some here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045077/edit-a-text-file-on-the-console-in-64-bit-windows

A useful thing to do is to make an alias called "edit" (for example) for your favorite text editor. Put something like this in your profile:

```
set-alias edit "${env:ProgramFiles}\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

Comment: Newer versions of Windows also have `powershell_ise.exe` built-in and in the path. A pretty good editor for PowerShell scripts.

Comment: so no built in powershell editor inside the shell? only external programs that run outside of powershell?

Comment: @John Demetriou, I'm not sure what you mean by "built in" now. There are two stock text editors that come with Windows: Notepad and PowerShell ISE (thanks Peter). If you want a console-based editor, then the link above has some. There is no stock, console-based editor in recent versions of Windows.

Comment: that's what I meant, stock console based editor. ok thanks. I will look in the link you provide and choose. thanks

Comment: To use the ISE editor: `psEdit \path\to\file.txt` ... To switch back and forth between the editor and powershell `ctrl + s` and `ctrl + d`

Comment: Using `notepad readme` is the best solution I've found for creating files on windows where you can control the file extension.

Answer (score 5):

**[Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)** ([choco pkg](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git)) has nano, vim (and prob'ly others) built in.  Setting a PowerShell alias/function will make them easier to launch.  E.g.:

```
function nano { C:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe --ignorercfiles $args }
```

Place this command in your shell startup script by:

1. Copying the command above
2. Paste into powershell console
3. Run "nano $profile"
4. Paste again into the script file
5. Ctl-X to save,exit

**EDIT**: Changed command to ignore syntax highlighting files (which doesn't work by default). Original command:

```
set-alias nano C:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

Nano editor has a win32 version, you can download it from here
https://nano-editor.org/dist/win32-support/

You can download "nano-git-0d9a7347243.exe" file, rename it to "nano.exe", and add the folder you saved the file in to the environment variable "Path".

Comment: how is this different from the other answers?

Comment: FYI: This version is from 2017

Comment: This suggestion was painless and exactly the solution. I give it the check! ✔

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers you've already received, you can have a shell editor in Windows, by installing Vim for windows, from Vim's official page.

https://www.vim.org/download.php

Answer (score 0):

#### Using MSYS and MinGW

Copy the produced binary `nano.exe` to your environment. You can get this:

##### From source

I installed [MYSYS](https://www.msys2.org) with [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org) and was able to:

```shell
$ pacman -S tar gcc ncurses ncurses-devel
$ f='nano-5.8'  # Change this line for a different v5 version
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf 'https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v5/'"$f"'.tar.xz'
$ tar xf "$f"'.tar.xz' && cd "$f"
$ ./configure
$ make  # See './src/nano.exe'
```

##### From pre-compiled package

```shell
$ pacman -S nano
```

to get it working in that environment:

#### From source (patched for Windows)

In case you keep getting `Error opening terminal: xterm-256color.` errors:

```shell
$ pacman -S git
$ git clone https://github.com/lhmouse/nano-win
$ cd nano-win  # tested on `38790067`
$ ./build_nano-win.sh
```

#### From archive

Or just download the package directly and add it to your `PATH`:

https://mirror.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/nano-5.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst (extract with [Modern 7-zip](https://www.tc4shell.com/en/7zip/modern7z/) + [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org), or [`unzstd`](https://github.com/facebook/zstd)) and `exe`s from `nano-5.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst\nano-5.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar\usr\bin\` to your `PATH`, along with (from `msys64\usr\bin\` or the archives): `msys-ncursesw6.dll`, `msys-2.0.dll`, `msys-magic-1.dll`, `msys-intl-8.dll`, `msys-iconv-2.dll`, `msys-bz2-1.dll`, `msys-z.dll`

---

#### Test, on `cmd.exe` (Windows Command Prompt)

```shell
> nano --version
 GNU nano, version 5.8
 (C) 1999-2011, 2013-2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 (C) 2014-2021 the contributors to nano
 Compiled options: --enable-utf8
```

If it works, invocation of `nano` will look like:

```
  GNU nano 5.8                        New Buffer




















               [ Welcome to nano.  For basic help, type Ctrl+G. ]
^G Help      ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut       ^T Execute   ^C Location
^X Exit      ^R Read File ^\ Replace   ^U Paste     ^J Justify   ^_ Go To Line
```